# Rails 4: jquery-turbolinks causing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

My Javascript is only loading after refreshing the page in Rails. After looking into it, the recommend solution seems to be to use turbolinks. However, when I include the jquery-turbolinks gem, JQuery itself seems to crash presumably due to some dependency error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

Here's what my application.js file is looking like

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require angular/angular.min
//= require angular/angular-route.min
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui.min
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require conversations
//= require analytics
//= require common
//= require jquery.infinite-pages
//= require jquery.contenthover
//= require overlay
//= require tag-it.min
//= require_tree .
//= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
```

So to sum it up, if I don't use jquery-turbolinks, my JS won't load until after a page refresh. If I do use it, jQuery crashes. If i try to put it before require jquery, it can't find the JQuery file and said $ is not a function.

Comment: you should replace `//= require jquery.turbolinks` with this `//= require turbolinks
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order the jQuery.turbolinks just after jQuery

```
//= require turbolinks
//= require angular/angular.min
//= require angular/angular-route.min
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui.min
```

That's the way the jQuery.turbolinks will work correctly